# Difference between optimisation algorithms and reinforcement learning methods

Tags: reinforcement-learning

I have a sense that one step task of reinforcement learning is essentially the same with some optimisation algorithms.

For example, suppose there is only one parameter `α` and we try to optimise `y` using gradient descent for optimisation, then in each iteration(or step), `α` is actually moving slightly towards the direction with `δy`. The step is exactly the same in reinforcement learning, where `δy` is named as temporal difference and `y` is the value of that state `S(a)`.

So, I wonder for 1 step reinforcement learning problems, is it actually a optimisation method, or can it be used to optimise parameters?(based on the context above)

I might have some misunderstanding on this, welcome to correctify.

Comment: Recently I saw a paper that likely doesn't answer your question but maybe is interesting to you: Discounted Reinforcement LearningIs Not an Optimization Problem [https://arxiv.org/pdf/1910.02140.pdf]

Answer (score 2):

First of all, reinforcement learning is very general. Almost any optimization problem can be transformed into a RL problem. It's usually not worth it, because a RL agent would select sub-optimal actions, doing trial and error just to confirm things you already know by design.

To your question: I think the similarity you found is that both algorithms make use of a (noisy) gradient step. Temporal difference is just one RL method of many. If I remember correctly it calculates the difference between the predicted value and the (noisy) value estimate made with the observed reward. It cannot simply set the correct value, because in general there is a complicated dependency between the values of other states, so instead it makes just one a small step to reduce the difference.

Sure, you could set up a RL task somehow to optimize `reward = y(α)`. Now `α` can either be the agent's "state", in which case you need actions decrement or increment it (you learn state-values) or `α` can be the action in which case there is only a single state (you learn action-values). With the right exploration strategy it might even work if you are patient. But in both cases you waste your knowledge about the gradient `δy(α)/δα` because the RL algorithm does not know about it. Yes it takes gradient-steps, but those gradients reduce the difference between the learned value and the actual value. If the true values are exactly the rewards (which is true if the agent dies after one step, and if there is no randomness when you evaluate `y(α)`) then this is wasted effort. Instead of taking a small step to smooth out the non-existing influence on other states, you could have just set it to the true value directly.

You mentioned "*one-step reinforcement learning*": what comes to mind is the [contextual bandit](https://getstream.io/blog/introduction-contextual-bandits/) setup. It's a simplification of the full-blown RL setup where your actions do not influence the next state (=context). The next simplification is the multi-armed bandit, which only has actions but no state/context.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. It resolves most my confusion. Your statement `If the true values are exactly the rewards, then this is wasted effort`, may I know why? Suppose MAB with no randomness, is it the same as gradient descent?